# How to gracefully close an ffmpeg process running in background without corrupting the encoded video file?

Tags: python, winapi, subprocess

I need to be able to stop it on demand. I tried to gracefully terminate the process with `taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe` but it doesn't work. If I force it with `/f` then the video file gets corrupted.

I think the alternatives could be:

- To get the process handle and then send a `q` keystroke to the stdin of that process running in background.
- To get the console back again so I can sent the input from the console.
- To use PyHooks and/or Win32Api to read keypresses, if a combination is pressed, then write to the stdin of the process.

This is the code (`rec.pyw`) I used to create the ffmpeg.exe process, hidden:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

# Creation flags
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200

cmd = sys._MEIPASS + os.sep + 'ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -vcodec libx264 -qp 0 -crf 0 -vf scale=1280x720 -preset ultrafast -an -y out.mp4'
r = subprocess.call(cmd.split(), shell=True) #creationflags=
```

Then I used pyinstaller to create an `exe` file with `ffmpeg` bundled:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --add-binary ffmpeg.exe;. rec.pyw
```

I used the `creationflags` parameters because I've read that with a detached process I could create the window again. But I haven't found how.

## Workaround

I've found that if I use `.mkv` instead of `.mp4` the file doesn't get corrupted when killing the ffmpeg process from the task manager.

Comment: Depends on exactly what you mean by "running in background".  If it has a console window, you may be able to bring it to the foreground and use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm updating the question to give more details on how I created the process.

Comment: *I've read that with a detached process I could create the window again* - from the process in question, certainly.  From *another* process, no.  Or at least not without great difficulty.  Since your code is launching the process in question, better to provide it with a standard input at that point; trying to do it retroactively is just causing trouble for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The following linked post taught me to cleanly stop ffmpeg from python by simulating a keypress of 'q':

[How to stop ffmpeg remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722624/how-to-stop-ffmpeg-remotely)

You create an empty file that you write 'q' to when you are ready to stop it.

To start the ffmpeg stream with python code, do this:

```
os.system("<stop /usr/bin/ffmpeg ...")
```

When ready to stop ffmpeg in your python code, do this:

```
os.system("echo 'q' >stop")
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

ffmpeg won't shut down cleanly because ffmpeg doesn't run with a window handle on windows, and only programs with a window handle can catch the `WM_CLOSE` event that the `taskkill` command sends.  In fact, ffmpeg isn't even designed to catch a `WM_CLOSE` event at all, so even if you create a window handle for ffmpeg with the `start` command, it's not going to shut down gracefully when you send the `taskkill`

### The Solution

The only real solution is to modify ffmpeg itself, or create a wrapper program that has a window handle and can catch the `WM_CLOSE` event.

I ran into the same issues and created a wrapper program to handle the `WM_CLOSE` event and shut down ffmpeg gracefully.  It's written in `nim` so you'll have to compile it or you can grab a release from the releases page:

https://github.com/Wykleph/ffmpeg_wrapper

You can launch ffmpeg with the wrapper and kill the wrapper's PID with `taskkill`.  When the wrapper gets the `WM_CLOSE` event it shuts down the ffmpeg process gracefully.  You can use `mp4` or whatever encoding you need.

`ffmpeg_wrap.exe ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 150M -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 448 -offset_y 240 -video_size 1024x600 -draw_mouse 1 -show_region 1 -i desktop -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -movflags +faststart screen-recording.mp4`

Run that and open up task manager, get the `pid` for the `ffmpeg_wrap.exe` process and send the `taskkill`

To use it in `python`, just start the `ffmpeg_wrap` process and get the PID, then run `taskkill` on the PID (you can do this in the same script) when you want it to shut down ffmpeg gracefully.

### The Catch

This program relies on a python dll file.  I'm new to `nim` and the only way I know how to keep an ffmpeg process open without hanging is with the python `subprocess` module.  Any of the python dll files that have the `subprocess` module should work.  I use `python3.8.dll`, so that should definitely work.  This file should be located at:

`C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps`

Answer (score 0):

In your python script you'll need to catch the signal with an except statement. I'm not a windows person, so I don't know how unix signals translate exactly to what you're sending, `taskkill`, but do a quick google on how to handle that in python and then in the except block you'll want to call a function that can finish writing the current frame and know to end after that frame is written and then do cleanup which may or may not involve writing more header/metadata to your file and then closing the file handle.

Comment: Windows doesn't have signals.  Besides, he's trying to shut down a third-party executable, not a Python script.